# select option dropdown: hide the default value from dropdown options

Tags: select, default, dropdown

I have a dropdown which should show a default value of current role of user. And the dropdown shows all roles. If the role is 'admin' I'm seeing admin, admin, user like this:

[image]

```
 <div class="col-md-9">
                  <select>
                    <option>{{data.role}}</option>
                    <option>Admin</option>
                    <option>User</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

How do I work with this to avoid seeing the roles twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
select option:checked {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: You using any custom select box (I'm assuming from you given image) or on which browser's you testing it?

Comment: i'm testing on chrome.

Comment: Yes I tested in chrome and it is working for me. Also see here they saying it is work even from IE9 here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp